# Am getting return nothing when I try to retrieve the last added document name in my firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when I try to get the last added doc name in firestore firebase I got returned nothing. The code is below

```
    // Get a reference to the collection
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'questions');

    // Query the collection to get the last added document
    const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('id', 'desc'), limit(1));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    let lastDocName = '';
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      lastDocName = doc.id;
    });
    console.log("Last Doc called: ", lastDocName);
```

Am naming my docs numbers like 1, 2, 3, ... but when I try to retrieve the last one so that I can increment it I get NaN but when I name the doc using Auto-id, it's only then with the code above I can get the doc name back

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If the problem is in the code you shared, can you copy/paste the exact output from the `console.log` statement into the question as well as a screenshot of a document that you'd expect this to return?

Comment: the problem is not the code, am using console.log the get outcome where sometime I get NaN when the doc name is a number but when using Auto-ID it can display the name

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to order the documents in their document ID metadata field. But your code (`orderBy('id', 'desc')`) actually order the documents on their `id` **field** from the data, and if none of your documents have such a field you'd get no results.

To order on the documents ID metadata, use the [`documentId` field path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#documentid):

```
orderBy(documentId(), 'desc')
```